# grep not listting obvious matches

Tags: terminal

I am trying to use vi-style key commands for the terminal and run

```
bind -p | grep -v '^#\|self-insert\|^$'
```

In the output from `bind -p` is a list of the commands and the keys they are binded to. In the list there are e.g. lines like

```
"d": self-insert
"e": self-insert
"f": self-insert
```

and my regex above correctly removes these lines (note the -v flag inverts the search). However, the above still matches a lot of lines (there are at least 30-40 identical lines) which are

```
"?": self-insert
"?": self-insert
"?": self-insert
```

Even if I try to specifically match the lines above by

```
bind -p | grep -e 'self-insert'
```

the output does not list these, but it catches the lines I mentioned further up!

Can someone please explain why this is? By search the internet I find that BSD grep seems to have a lot of issues. Perhaps this is a bug?

Comment: Just to clarify, my regex in the first command in the post is suppose to match lines starting with `#`, lines containing the words `self-insert` and empty lines.

Comment: Try `egrep` instead of `grep`.

Comment: I tried both egrep and grep -E with the same result. However, I just tried the same thing on my work computer (a slightly newer Macbook Pro) and here it works as expected! It is strange since both computers have the same grep version.